# Why does composing a Clifford circuit to another circuit not work? (Qiskit)

Tags: qiskit, clifford-group

I need to use a random Clifford operator and add it to another circuit. However, the Clifford operator does not seem to be there after application of `compose`. An example code which illustrates the problem is:

```
import qiskit as qk
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_clifford
from qiskit.quantum_info import Clifford

qc = qk.QuantumCircuit(3)
U = random_clifford(3,seed=123)
U = Clifford.to_circuit(U)
qc.compose(U,qubits=[0,1,2])
qc.draw("mpl")
```

If I draw `U` alone, it gives a nice example of a random Clifford gate. Thus, I guess the error lies in the application of `compose`, but how can I solve this? It does not throw an error, it just does not happen anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, [`compose()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.compose.html) method returns the composed circuit and keep the original circuit unchanged. For in-place composition, you need to set `inplace` parameter to `True`:

```
qc.compose(U,qubits=[0,1,2], inplace=True)
```

Comment: perfect, thank you!